# How to trace how/where the printf is disabled?

Tags: c, tcl

My product embeds TCL VM to run TCL script. We basically take the TCL 8.4 source and integrate it to our product, the whole product is programmed in C.

Now I need to debug some issue and best I can have some insight about TCL VM at run time. So I add some printf to the TCL source, but I cannot see any print out. Note that the printf added to our side of the code works as expected.

This leads me to suspect that somewhere in TCL the printf is disabled.

I see the following code snippet in TCL source:

```
#ifdef TCL_COMPILE_DEBUG
  fprintf(stdout, "  Starting stack top=%d\n", eePtr->stackTop);
  fflush(stdout);
#endif
```

I rebuild TCL by enabling the TCL_COMPILE_DEBUG, still I cannot see print out.

Any suggestion how I should proceed from here?

Comment: You can put a `#error tcl_debug` after the `#ifdef` to verify that the compiler will place the `fprintf` in the executable. There's still the question of how many run-time conditions must be met before the `fprintf` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that the standard library's `fprintf()` is disabled.  Instead, I see three main alternatives:

1. The `fprintf()` you have added is never being called.  That could be because it's in the wrong place, because conditional compilation directives cause it to be omitted, or perhaps for some other reason.
2. The `fprintf()` being called is not the standard library's, and it does not do what you expect.  It might instead be a local function in the TCL VM's code, or the TCL VM might `#define` it to something else altogether.  Depending on exactly how you integrate TCL into your larger code, these possibilities might be limited in scope to just TCL.
3. `stdout` does not mean what you think it does inside the TCL code.  This would almost surely be as a result of it being `#define`d to something else, for some reason important to the TCL VM.  In that case, there might or might not be a way to get the real `stdout` in that scope.

I'd suggest you grep the TCL code you have integrated for the `fprintf` and `stdout` symbols, to look for macro definitions and alternative implementations.  It would also be worthwhile to check the preprocessor output to make sure your call is still there (and is still the call you expected).  If you are compiling with GCC, then you can preprocess your sources without compiling the result via `gcc -E`.

Comment: Tcl leaves `fprintf` and `stdout` on the standard meanings, and only ever uses them for debugging.